# How does Silverlight Background Worker update the UI thread without problems?

Tags: silverlight, multithreading

I am using the Background worker thread in a Silverlight 4 application.  In the ProgresssChanged event handler, I can make calls to the Silverlight UI, but how does this work ?  Isn't the background worker thread that fires the ProgressChanged event on a different thread from the Silverlight UI thread ?  If so, I thought updating the UI thread from another thread causes exceptions.

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that updating the UI Thread from another thread is a no-no. BackgroundWorker has special smarts to make sure, even though work is being done on a background thread, the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events are raised on the UI Thread.

I believe it makes use of [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) to do this.

Comment: Hmm.  Just read SynchronizationContext and I must confess, it didn't shed a lot of light on it for me.  I am guessing the Background worker thread inherits from this ?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 It does use the `SynchronizationContext` to ensure that the Progress and Completed events occur on the __same__ thread that called the `RunWorkerAsync`.  As result its only safe to update the UI from these events if the `RunWorkerAsync` was actually called from the UI Thread.  BackgroundWorker doesn't specifically seek out the UI Thread.